# Can top quark decay into a top quark and a $W$ boson?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model

I have a question regarding Figure 1 from this paper:
https://cds.cern.ch/record/2859612/files/TOP-22-008-pas.pdf

[image]

How can a top quark decay into a top quark and a $W^{-}$ boson?

Comment: Mike stone's answer is right... but I also want to note that the horizontal line is a virtual particle. Feynman diagrams aren't depictions of particles that existed for a short time then decayed into other particles. So even with the fix of $b$ replacing $t$, it isn't correct to phrase it as "a $b$ quark decays into $t$ and $W^-$". Unfortunately to properly understand the meaning of these diagrams one needs to study QFT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a typo. The horizontal line should be a "b" with charge -1/3 rather than a "t" with charge +2/3. This is clear because the incoming "b" has emited a charge neutral gluon, and therefore remains a "b".